# Combine two db tables to display in a single html table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have a table for categories and a table for tags.

I can query and limit and paginate these fine, however what I really want to be able to do is combine these and then sort alphabetically as well as paginate.

It's not something i've done before, so I wonder if it's even possible using existing tools or I am going to have to write the query manually and add in the pagination etc.

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')->sortBy('Title')->paginate(20);
```

will work for that, but want them both, sorted by Title and paginating.

Possible?

Comment: Are you asking how to code a [Union all](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use PHP arrays.

array_push() your two table results into one array. Then use the sort() function for alphabetical order.

Comment: That would mean fetching ALL the data from the database, looping over and building an array, then I only want 20 of the 500... so a bit of a waste...